# Why do I get "Reverse for '' with arguments '()' not found"?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am beginner at Django.

In fact, I'mtrying to create a dashboard from which it is possible to go to every model. A single "page-config.html" reads the model concerned and diplays its content. From this page I want to be able to create a new row or update or delete. THe page in charge of it is called "page-config-detail".

let's see it.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', home, name="home"),
    path('prestations/', prestations, name="prestations"),
    path('realisations/', realisations, name="realisations"),
    path('contact/', contact, name="contact"),

    path('dashboard/', dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('dashboard/<page_name>', pageConfig, name="page-config"),
    path('dashboard/<page_name>/<action>/<int:element_id>', pageConfigDetail, name="page-config-detail"),

]
```

My views.py

```
def pageConfig(request, page_name):
    create = 'create'
    for page in MY_CONFIG_PAGES:
        if page[0] == page_name:
            model = page[1].objects.all()
        else :
            return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
    return render(request, "pages/page-config.html", {'model' : model, 'create' : create, 'category': 'category'} )

def pageConfigDetail(request, page_name=None, action=None, element_id=None):
    for page in MY_CONFIG_PAGES:
        if page[0] == page_name:
            if action == "create" or action == "update" or action == "delete" :
                try:
                    model = page[1].objects.get(pk=element_id)
                    if request.method == "POST":
                        if action == "update":
                            form = page[2](request.POST, instance=model)
                        elif action =="delete":
                            """faudra faire une redirection""" 
                        else:
                            """faire un http redirect vers l'update et pas create"""
                            pass
                        if form.is_valid():
                            form.save()
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'dashboard/{page[0]}')
                    else: 
                        form = page[2](instance=model)

                except  ObjectDoesNotExist :
                    if request.method == "POST":
                        if action == "create":
                            form = page[2](request.POST)
                        else:
                            """on redirige vers create """

                        if form.is_valid():
                            form.save()
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'dashboard/{page[0]}')
                    else :
                        form = page[2]()     
            else :
                return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard/')   
        else :
            return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard/') 
        
    return render(request, "pages/page-config-detail.html", {form : form})
```

My template: page-config.html

```
{% load static %}

{% for m in model %}

{{ m }}

{% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'page-config-detail' category create %}">Ajouter</a>
```

here is the error message:

````
NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/category
Reverse for 'page-config-detail' with arguments '('category', 'create')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/(?P<action>[^/]+)/(?P<element_id>[0-9]+)$']```


I tried a lot of things but I'm not able to understand what is the problem. Thank you for your help.
````

Comment: `page-config-detail` url expects an `element_id`.

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to make this element_id optional?

Comment: Why do you add it to the url pattern if you don't need it? Remove it from the url config or send a value to the view.

Comment: I just want to add an optional value to it when i want to update I can put an id but when i want to create i don't want to put an id. But it works. Thank you for help Marco.

Comment: Maybe you're just missing a path with just 2 arguments for the create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
path('dashboard/<page_name>/<action>/<int:element_id>', 
     pageConfigDetail, name="page-config-detail"),
```

which has kwargs, not args. Keywords `action` and `element_id`. So your `{% url` doesn't match. You (presumably) want

```
{% url 'page-config-detail' action=category element_id=create %}
```

or maybe other values (didn't read your code in full), but the keywords are mandatory.

re: *Is it possible to make this element_id optional?*

Yes. Either have another url for the same view with just one arg and (important) a different name

```
path('dashboard/<page_name>/<action>/', 
     pageConfigDetail, name="page-config-detail_1"),
```

Or simpler, provide an "impossible" value (`0` is common) when you `reverse`, and have your Python code treat this value specially.

Comment: I put it but nothing change `path('dashboard/<str:page_name>/<str:action>/<int:element_id>', pageConfigDetail, name="page-config-detail"),
`
my template 
`<a href="{% url 'page-config-detail' page_name=category action=create %}">Ajouter</a>
`